# How to test push notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We have a live app which sends push notifications just fine.

New version of the app, not yet released - we want to test that push notification works, but it seems all we can test is that the service is working. This test version which uses the 'sandbox' doesn't actually send a push to a development phone ....

Is this right? Is there a way I can test this new version of the app AND receive push notifications to my device?

Been trying to crack it for several days now.
Thanks in advance!
Andy

Comment: are you using a particular service to send pushes? or do you have your own server side implementation?

Comment: We have our own server sending the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need distribute the Distribution version of your app using [ad hoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html).

When your application  ready for submission, you create an ad hoc provisioning profile specifying an App ID that matches one or more of your apps, a set of test devices, and a single distribution certificate.

Here is an image to illustrate how the provision profile  works:

[image]

Comment: "In order to test your app for push notifications you will have to wait for it to be approved." Thats just not correct

Comment: Guys please read the full answer, I said `If that's not an option you can still distribute the Distribution version of your app using ad hoc.`

Comment: Regardless, it still doesn't actually answer HOW to test.

Comment: @Piepants yes it does , to test the app you need to ditribute using adhoc

Comment: Thanks very much everybody, I have clarity! I think :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first test the app in isolation to check that is working, then when it is move on to testing the app and server in combination.

To test your app in isolation run it in Xcode and put in a breakpoint or NSLog to find out what the APN token is.
Then use the php script from here

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

using your APN token and credentials.

It should work, and it should work in the sandbox, if it doesn't then your app isn't correctly configured so work at investigating why it doesn't work until you can send it a push manually.

THen once you can send a push manually test you can send one using your server, if you can't then it must be due to a problem with the server as you have just confirmed the app is working. If the server isn't working its probably not using the credentials or applying the password to the credentials, something like that

Comment: why does this have 4 upvotes? it does not even answer the question smh

Comment: In the link given above you will get a file simplepush.php execute this file through the terminal using the commands which are given in d same link, and just replace your device token in the simplepush.php file, also if you are in the development mode make sure to mention the gateway address as gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195..you will receive the push notifications successfully